# Receiving a region error deploying Firebase Functions with Google Cloud Task client

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

### Problem

When I deploy my Firebase Functions importing Google Cloud Tasks `@google-cloud/tasks` I receive a region errror.

To demonstrate this I include the code giving successful and unsuccessful deployment.

### Successfull

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

admin.initializeApp();

export const helloWorld = functions.region("europe-west3").https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

### Unsuccessful

`CloudTaskClient` and `onDeletePostCancelTask` function are added to the successful code.

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
const {CloudTasksClient} = require("@google-cloud/tasks");

admin.initializeApp();
const tasksClient = new CloudTasksClient();

export const helloWorld = functions.region("europe-west3").https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});

export const onDeletePostCancelTask = functions.region("europe-west3").database
    .ref("/one/{twoId}").onDelete(async (snapshot, context) => {
      const dogId = snapshot.key;
      const taskSnap = await snapshot.ref.parent?.parent?.child("three/" + twoId).get();
      const taskName = taskSnap?.val();
      console.log("Task name: ", taskName);
      return tasksClient.deleteTask({name: taskName});
    });
```

##### Error:

```
Error: There was an error deploying functions:
- Error Failed to create function helloWorld in region europe-west3
- Error Failed to create function onDeletePostCancelTask in region europe-west3
```

In Firebase Functions log I found the following:

```
Provided module can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module '@google-cloud/tasks'
Require stack: 
- /workspace/lib/index.js 
...
```

### More Info

- I was following the installation process as described in [How to schedule a Cloud Function to run in the future with Cloud Tasks (to build a Firestore document TTL)](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a).
- My Firebase app region is europe-west3.
- My Google Cloud app region is europe-west. (However, at the beggigning configuring the Cloud Tasks I created new project with us-central1 region, but since there was an instance of my project with europe-west region I switched to it.)
- When I omit `.region("europe-west3")` the error stays, just with us-central1 instead.
- I have two `package.json`, first in `../` the second in `../functions/`. The outer one has the `@google-cloud/tasks` dependency :

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/tasks": "^2.4.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.16.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to include `@google-cloud/tasks` in the `package.json` file in the `../functions` directory.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer! Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function deployment failed because it cannot find the `@google-cloud/tasks` in `package.json` in your function directory and there's no problem about region concern. It can't be deployed to any region if there's a missing dependency in your function.

To fix it and add the `@google-cloud/tasks` dependency in your `function/package.json`, run the following command in your `function` directory:

```
npm install @google-cloud/tasks
```

Deploy again, and it should be successful.

Comment: Thats it! Such a minor detail, but so much time lost. Thanks

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! I had packages installed in the root folder and it kept failing. -Maybe the docs can elaborate on this  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯